# Converting a NgDateStruct object into a String

Tags: angular, typescript, ngb-datepicker

I am having a variable which is a NgbDateStruct object in the typescript file and would like to convert it into a String of the following format: "YYYY-MM-DD".

```
 currentDate: NgbDateStruct;
```

When I console.log(this.currentDate) it is showing a Moment object.

```
console.log(this.currentDate);
```

> Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: '2021-12-1', _f: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
> _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
> _d: Wed Dec 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time) {}
> _f: "YYYY-MM-DD"
> _i: "2021-12-1"
> _isAMomentObject: true
> _isUTC: false
> _isValid: true
> _locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: 'Invalid date', _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
> ordinal: ƒ, …}
> _pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …} [[Prototype]]: Object

How would I be able to extract the format "YYYY-MM-DD" that is already existing in this object that is shown in the console.log?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a moment object then you can get string date by formatting it this way

```
console.log(this.currentDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that earlier but NgbDateStruct does not have a property format unlike Date.